# How accurate is the approximation of the number of rough numbers?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-factorization

A number is called a $y$-rough number, if it has no prime divisor below $y$.

The number of rough numbers in an interval, lets say, $[10^{99},10^{100}]$ is approximately the length of the interval multiplied with $\prod1-\frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ runs over the primes below $y$.

However, if $\ 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot p$ is not much smaller than the length of the interval, the approximation should have a considerable deviation of the actual value.

The article in Wikipedia only gives asymptotic formulas, so my questions :

> How accurate is the naive approximation ?
>
> How can I determine the number of $y$-rough numbers in an interval reasonably accurate ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [Buchstab function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function).

Let $\Phi(x,y)$ be the number of positive integers $n\leq x$ which do not have any prime divisor $p< y$.  Then it is known that for any fixed $U>1$

$$
\Phi(x,y)=\frac{x w(u)}{\log y} - \frac y{\log y} +O\left(\frac x{(\log x)^2} \right)
$$
where $y=x^{\frac 1u}$ with $1\leq u\leq U$ , $y\geq 2$, and $w(u)$ satisfies
$$
w(u)=\frac 1u  \ \ \textrm{ for }1\leq u \leq 2, 
$$
$$
(uw(u))'=w(u-1) \ \ \textrm{ for }u>2.
$$
Also, it is known that $w(u)\rightarrow e^{-\gamma}$ as $u\rightarrow\infty$.

You may find more information in Montgomery & Vaughan's 'Multiplicative Number Theory', Classical Theory, Chapter 7.

Comment: I already found this. But the "O"-notation does not say anything about the accuracy. The product $\prod (1-1/p)$ can be very well approximated by $\exp(-\gamma)/\ln(p)$, but this does not imply that the number of rough numbers is very well aproximated as well.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by well approximated. The function $w(u)$ is not a constant function, and it is approaching to $\exp(-\gamma)$ when $u\rightarrow\infty$. So, for small $u$, replacing $w(u)$ by $\exp(-\gamma)$ gives an incorrect asymptotic formula.

Comment: I would like to have a reasonable estimate of the error I make, if I use the approximation. And I wonder, whether a method is known giving more precise results.